# SFTP - how to configure the path

Tags: linux, sftp

I want to know how to configure the path of downloaded files via sftp in Linux (Centos 7.2 or 7.6). I tried to edit /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and I didn’t find any mention of a path.

For example – I want to download the configuration from a device – I downloaded – where can I determine where the file will exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you used

```
get remote-file
```

then the file `remote-file` will have been downloaded in the directory in which your invoked `sftp`.

The `get` command also allows you to specify a local path relative to the current directory:

```
get remote-file local-dir
```

While connected with `sftp` to a server, you may *change* the local directory by using

```
lcd new-dir
```

This is equivalent to having started `sftp` from within the local directory `new-dir`.  Any files downloaded with `get` would then be put into that directory (unless a local directory path was specified with `get`).

Note that using `lcd` only changes the current directory of the `sftp` client.  When you exit the client, you will still be in the same directory from which you invoked the `sftp` client.

---

Note that `vsftpd` is an FTP server that implements a secure variant of the FTP protocol (FTPS).  This software has nothing to do with `sftp`.  Apart from that, the download destination is not something that is handled by the server, but by the client that is downloading the files.

Comment: Thanks. but I downloaded from an application and not from my server. I can't know where the file saved via an application. So I need to know it via sftp in the server.

Comment: @ShalevSason Please update the question with information that will help us help you. When you say you download files with `sftp`, I must assume that you used `sftp` on the command line (since you give no further information). It is also unclear what you mean by your comment; `sftp` downloads files from remote servers. The location of the downloaded files is decided on the client side, not on the server side. Downloading "from an application" does not make sense.